# How to make drop-down or vertical list in CMS block?

Tags: magento-1.9, drop-downs

In my multi-vendor setup I have created a static CMS block which is visible at the navigation menu. It shows the vendor_id and logo together.

I use the identifier `pt_item_menu_list_vendors` with the following code.

```
{{block type="vendors/list" name="vendors.list" vendor_ids="3,13"}}
```

This works but it doesn't get well organized as vendors are located horizontal next to each other. How to make a list or drop-down for my vendors so that you can see name and logo. Logo has to be resized till thumbnail.

Comment: show user you template I guess